# Mosaico templates don't work

Tags: email, mailing, mosaico

I have loaded Civicrm on a localhost. Everything works fine. I enabled the Mosaico extension. To do this I installed an ImageMagick plugin on Wordpress, enabled the Flexmailer and the Shoreditch theme. When I go into Mosaico, I get the message Warning Experimental Beta Version Use with Care. The templates are also blank as per the illustration. Is there a way around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was caused by installing an old version of Mosaico. I installed the orginal extension version and not the latest one. I  uninstalled the old extension and installed the proper one.